# conditional formatting entire row if cell contains text

Tags: excel, excel-2010, row, conditional-formatting

I have an excel sheet where I'm trying to use conditional formatting but it doesn't seem to work as I would like it to.

It seems as though any formula won't work as I don't want the cell to match TBC, but contain it.

In short, I am looking for this:

If D2 Contains "TBC" then highlight the whole row

I've tried around 10 suggestions through Google and also Stack Overflow but it seems as thou

Note: Each cell will have different values, i.e. D2 has "1 screenshot TBC" and D3 has "5 screenshots TBC". As they will all have different values but all contain the abbreviation "TBC" I am trying to search for that word.

Any help or advice that could be offered will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time! :)

Amandip

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276769/conditional-formatting-entire-row-if-any-cell-contains-the-specified-text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select your entire sheet and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=FIND("TBC",$D1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour Fill (highlight) of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Change `FIND` to `SEARCH` if you want this case insensitive.

This will trigger for the likes of `ATBCX`.

Comment: This worked perfectly (after I changed the value to match my dimensions as I realised I forgot that from the initial post. Thank you very much!