# excel conditional formatting: highlight the rest of a row after a certain character is entered into a cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a row containing 35 or so cells. I would like to be able to conditionally format all cells to the right of a certain character - ie #.

'#' can be added at any point in the row.

Cells to the left of the # will retain other existing conditional formatting rules and not be overwritten.

Data validation exists on all cells.

the nearest I can get is the answer here
[Conditional Formatting Entire Row If Any Cell Contains the Specified Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276769/conditional-formatting-entire-row-if-any-cell-contains-the-specified-text)

but this highlights the entire row - and overwrites conditional formatting in the row prior to the #.

My sheet contains 75 rows that I need to behave like this (independently of course).

Can anyone help please? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your columns are A through AI.

Set all the columns for the rule and use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:A1,"#")>0
```

Then choose the fill you want.

[image]

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you!

And if I wanted to repeat the '#' through all the restof teh cells to the right of the initial # - how could I do that please?

Comment: @Gideon that is a different question and requires vba.

Comment: would that go in the excel objects for the sheet in question?